# Merging close objects after gaussian filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying to count the number of objects from an Image and stumbled upon the following code from another question, I applied it on my sample image as follows:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc, ndimage
from skimage import feature
from skimage.filters import roberts, sobel

im = misc.imread('/home/nvp/temp/kaw.png',flatten=True)
im = im.astype('int32')
edges1 = feature.canny(im, sigma=3)
plt.imshow(edges1,interpolation='nearest')
dx = ndimage.sobel(im, 1)  # horizontal derivative
dy = ndimage.sobel(im, 0)  # vertical derivative
mag = numpy.hypot(dx, dy)  # magnitude
mag *= 255.0 / numpy.max(mag)
dna = mag
dnaf = ndimage.gaussian_filter(dna, 7)
T = 27 # set threshold by hand to avoid installing `mahotas` or
       # `scipy.stsci.image` dependencies that have threshold() functions

# find connected components
labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(dnaf > T) # `dna[:,:,0]>T` for red-dot case
print(dnaf, labeled,len(labeled))
print("Number of objects is %d " % nr_objects)

# show labeled image
####scipy.misc.imsave('labeled_dna.png', labeled)
####scipy.misc.imshow(labeled) # black&white image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imsave('labeled_dna.png', labeled)
plt.imshow(labeled)
plt.show()
```

However it outputs the following image:

[image: Output]

The final objects are stored in `labeled` np.array I guess, What I'd like to do is merge close objects in this output array.  As you can see the second object in the last row has two parts but they are very close to each other.

As I've no idea of numpy , I'd like a way to set a threshold and merge objects that have smaller distance between them. Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two objects you want to merge are as close as the objects 3 and 4 of the first row... So a solution based only on the proximity between objects won't give you what you want.

One solution could be to [dilate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) your objects according to their area (dilating more small objects).

Example (not tested):

```
import scipy.ndimage.morphology as morpho

# parameters
max_dilat = 20 # dilation (in number of pixels) for a small object
sz_small = 100 # size of a small object (max dilated)
sz_big   = 10000 # size of a big object (not dilated)

result = labeled*0

# for each detected object
for obj_id in range(1, nr_objects+1):
    # creates a binary image with the current object
    obj_img = (labeled==obj_id)
    # computes object's area
    area = numpy.sum(obj_img)
    # dilatation factor inversely proportional to area
    dfac = int( max_dilat*(1-min(1,(max(0,area-sz_small)/sz_big))) )
    # dilates object
    dilat = morpho.binary_dilation(obj_img, iterations=dfac)

    result += dilat

# result is now an int array with ones where you have a single 
# dilated object, and twos (or more) in overlapping parts
labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(result>0)
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit and show an example I can follow ?

Comment: I added pseudo code, I can't test it now but it should work. Do not hesitate to play with the parameters to achieve the expected result.

Comment: Hi , I changed the values to `max_dilat=9, sz_small=90, sz_big=10000` and the results are as follows: [results](http://imgur.com/a/FPysS) , as you can see one of the objects is disappearing after dilating, any idea how to counter this? Thank you very much!

Comment: My bad, the last object was not processed (for obj_id in range(1, nr_objects **+1**))

Comment: Thank you , I'll accept the answer in a bit, I appreciate the help :)